# No field delimiter in outgoing FIX messages?

Tags: python, quickfix

I am using quickfix, compiled from the source on a linux box, setup to use the python headers.  Everything 'seems' fine when I run my code, but I can't log on to my FIX server, and I noticed that the messages I'm sending have no field/tag delimiters, all the fields and values are just mashed together...

What might be causing this? Am I missing some setup in 'FIX_Settings.txt'?

Thanks!

Comment: hmm... why is this getting downvoted? Let me know if I can be more clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would comment with this, but I don't have enough reputation. So - I'm not sure why you can't log into your server, but are you sure that you don't have delimiters? Because if you're using `\x01` as a delimiter in FIX, the tag-values pairs will usually just be displayed as "all mashed together," but the hex dump of it reveals otherwise (coming from personal experience).

Also, you might be getting downvoted because you haven't provided much context. If you provided the relevant bit of code or what your FIX output looks like, that might help.

Comment: You are correct! The delimiter was there, just not being displayed by the 'print' function. Thanks!